# grouping data in d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im creating a small d3 (http://d3js.org/) pie chart where some pieces of the pie are separated
and translated away from the center of the pie on hover. 
So far i managed separating the different parts of the pie and translating them away from the center of the circle, but they are translated separatedly. My goal is to group the pieces and translate them away together.
Im very new to d3js.

Basically what I want to achieve is grouping some of the elements and translating them away from the center of origin grouped.
Right now the pieces are translated separately and Im guessing that I can fix the problem by adding a parent and translating that parent away from the center.

So basically my question is :

**How can i group pieces of data (fx the ones labeled food) and translate that group away from the center of origin?**

The project can be found below and the content of the csv file in the bottom. Copy paste the code into a html-document and copy paste the csv data into a file named 'data.csv' located in the same folder.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<!--https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="r2d3.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->

<script>

// dimension
var width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// colors
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

//append svg to body
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arcs")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) {
                return data[i].class;  // i is 0-based.
            });

//        Select all classes named 'pizza' and translate away from center of circle
    svg.selectAll('.food')
            .attr("transform", function(d) {    //set the origin to the center of the arc
            //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = 0;
            x = arc.centroid(d)[0];
            y = arc.centroid(d)[1];
            return "translate(" + x/4 +','+ y/4 + ")";        //this gives us a pair of coordinates like [50, 50]
         });


    // color fill
    g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

    // append text
    g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";     })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
});
</script>
```

//content of csv file :

```
age,population,class
<5,2704659,food
5-13,4499890,food
14-17,2159981,food
18-24,3853788,icecream
25-44,14106543,icecream
45-64,8819342,pizza
≥65,612463,pizza
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1) Create an outer pie chart with a single pie segment for each class, then create addition pie charts inside each outer pie segment. The inner pie charts need to specify a start/end angle for their piechart (which matches the outer pie segment for that class). Here's a example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cblP4d?p=preview

2) Instead of translating each datapoint individually, create an array of translations for each class. Each class's translation uses the centroid for that class. When you translate each arc, use the translation array (referenced by class).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.